# Mozilla PDF.js Font Issue

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mozilla, pdf.js

I am trying to use Mozilla's PDF.js and when I load up the pdf I get this error in the console can anyone help?

> Error: FontFile not found for font: JYEMBF_HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman in pdf.js 21

Comment: I thought I had I used the Desktop to do the installs

Comment: @Brad Can you tell me how I would do this I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with the PDF, not a missing font on your system.  I'd recommend you file an issue at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues and link to the problematic PDF.